# Is it possible to automatically add a google script to each file that gets added to a folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I want to run a script onOpen() of each document in a folder on google drive.

Is there a  way I can automatically add the script to all new files?

Thanks

Comment: It might be possible to create a script, deploy it as a Documents-bound app, install it for *every* document, but the first thing it does is check if the active document is in the folder you are talking about.

Comment: @AJFMEDIA Can I ask you about the situation of ``automatically``? For example, when a script creates new Google Document, do you want to add a script as the container-bound script? Or do you want to add a script to the existing Google Document using a script as the container-bound script? Although it is possible to achieve these, if you want other situation, can I ask you about it?

Comment: I'm using Zapier to generate google docs based filled with information posted from a form, one part of the data is a base64 string of a signature. I have written a script that onopen grabs the base64 string and converts it into an actual inline image, but I would have to add that script to every new doc manually. Which is pointless. What I would like to achieve is to have that script automatically pre-applied to any new google docs so that when i open it up for the first time, the signature is automatically displayed. @tanaike

Comment: @AJFMEDIA Thank you for replying. I think that you should update your question and tags. It will help users think of about your issue. How about this?